# selenium server looks cut part off from the http request

Tags: selenium

I'm practicing Selenium, I got a strange issue and couldn't find the reason for a while.

In my Mac, I started a Selenium standalone server and a selenium web driver.

In Elciplse, I coded my Selenium scripts, created a Selenium instance as told like this:

```
selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444,
    "*chrome", "http://sydney.mycompany.net.au/GBT");
```

http://sydney.mycompany.net.au/" is an internal web of our company.

When I started JUnit, it looks my selenium server didn't sent `GET /GBT` to our web server (I checked the wireshark trace), only the first part (http://sysney.mycompany.net.au) was counted, but `/GBT` was cut off.

If I changed the url to `www.google.com.au`, everything is fine.

I tried some public web page such as `www.dailytelegraph.com.au/lifestyle`, I got the same problem: the `lifestyle` was cut off too.

Is there any settings I need to do on seleniume server or driver side? Very thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize selenium, base url is specified (i.e. domain name). After your base url was specified, you can navigate to internal web pages via `selenium.open("/GBT")`